# rename long file names while keeping a part of the name

Tags: bash, shell

I have a lot of files which have a certain pattern:

```
some123_name4.with5.number01-02_and6-other7.stuff.txt
some123_name4.with5.number05-06_and6-other7.stuff.txt
some123_name4.with5.number11-12_and6-other7.stuff.txt
```

and I would like to rename them keeping the part in the middle *number??-??*. For example like:

```
different45_start.keep76.number01-02_but.change34_rest.txt
different45_start.keep76.number05-06_but.change34_rest.txt
different45_start.keep76.number11-12_but.change34_rest.txt
```

I have played around with expr, %% and ? but I didn't even manage to extract the *number??-??* part of the filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ought to do it (replace with actual patterns)

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in some123* ; do
   mv $f `echo $f | sed -e 's/some123_name4.with5/different45_start.keep76/' -e 's/and6-other7.stuff/but.change34_rest/'`
done
```

Comment: Note that the above assumes the old file names all start and end with identical patterns

Comment: This very nice, simple and easy.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest you use regexp'es to extract your numbers from the old name into the new name? Then it's just a question about

- creating a new subdirectory (just in case you make a mistake)
- using "ls" to list the file names (with options for 1 (one) name per line, not following down into subdirs)
- iterating over the file names

In each iteration,

- set the new name
- run the copy commande "cp" using the old and the new names (but as a trick, copy down into your new subdirectory)

All in all, something like this:

```
mkdir NEW
ls -1d some* \
| while read FILE; do
        NEWFILE=`echo "$FILE" \
        | sed 's|^some12\\([0-9]\\)_name\\([0-9]\\)[.]with\\([0-9]\\)[.]number\\([0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]\\)_and\\([0-9]\\)-other\\([0-9]\\)[.]stuff[.]txt$|different\\2\\3_start.keep\\6\\5.number\\4_but.change\\1\\2_rest.txt|'`
        cp "$FILE" NEW/"$NEWFILE"
done
```

As you can see, due to the backticks (`) you have to use extra backslashes in the regexp.

Does this help you, as a start?

Comment: That looks very interesting! Thanks for showing something new and explain it :)

Answer (score 1):

a possible solution using `expr` looks like the following:

```
for f in *number??-??*; do
    fixedPart=$(expr "$f" : '.*\(number[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]\).*')
    newName="different45_start.keep76.${fixedPart}_but.change34_rest.txt"
    mv "$f" "$newName"
done
```

Comment: This is the way I was actually searching for, thanks a lot for that!